# Is there a 'ccache' for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build, ccache

I am aware that `scons` implements the functionality of `ccache`, but I am stuck with another build system.

I also know there is a `gocache` project on SourceForge that aims to implement `ccache`-like functionality for other compilers, but it seems not complete.

Answer (score 34):

A shameless plug, but I wrote a Python script which attempts to work just like ccache, except that it can wrap MSVC. See https://github.com/frerich/clcache

Comment: The github repo is marked as archived, so I assume this is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 7):

There's an [unofficial patch](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~kendy/ccache/) to ccache [to support MSVC](http://old.nabble.com/ccache-for-MSVC-td11396807.html), but I haven't yet tried it myself...

Comment: All information went away and there's no more textual description of how that was accomplished

Comment: Nowadays, ccache has "B" level support for MSVC: https://ccache.dev/platform-compiler-language-support.html So that patch is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/inorton/cclash

It is a bit more of a plug. I've been using it to shave about 35% off our Cygwin Visual Studio 2012 builds.

Answer (score 3):

[Stashed](https://stashed.io)

It supports PDB, PCH, and has a nice dashboard.

Comment: I think it is important to mention that stashed.io is not free but needs a license, because ccache is free.

Comment: Might no longer be maintained, last release in 2019 and several links on the homepage are dead.

Answer (score 3):

Incredibuild is very nice, though it is more like [distcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distcc) for Visual Studio than ccache.

If you want both ccache and distcc for a Visual Studio environment, try [Stashed](https://stashed.io) along with Incredibuild at the same time. It works a lot like [ccache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ccache) + distcc for Linux, without the configuration or administrative overhead.

Comment: Incredibuild is also not free